# Windows Phone 8 ApplicationBar expanded unchangable transparancy

Tags: windows-phone-8, transparent, appbar

following Code...

```
<!--Navigation-Bar-->
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" ForegroundColor="White" IsMenuEnabled="True" BackgroundColor="#002B55">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Click="B_Search_Click" IconUri="Images\Pic_Search.png" Text="Search"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Click="B_Media_Click" IconUri="Images\Pic_Media.png" Text="Media"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Click="B_Scan_Click" IconUri="Images\Pic_Scan.png" Text="Scanner"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Click="B_Charts_Click" IconUri="Images\Pic_Charts.png" Text="Charts"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Click="B_Logout_Click" Text="Logout"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

gives me following ApplicationBar...

http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3341/4xiadbvz_jpg.htm
(Solid background when expanded)

*BUT* if I create the AppBar in CodeBehind like this...

```
 private void ResetApplicationBar()
        {
            ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
            ApplicationBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(150, 0, 43, 85);;
            ApplicationBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
            ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1;

            ApplicationBarIconButton B_Search = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
            B_Search.IconUri = new Uri("/Images/Pic_Search.png", UriKind.Relative);
            B_Search.Text = "search";
            ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(B_Search);
            B_Search.Click += new EventHandler(B_Search_Click);

            (more Buttons...)
```

then I get that misterios unchangable Transparency...

http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3341/zjo57e37_jpg.htm
(Half-Transparent when expanded)

How can I change the Background to solid???
-Yes I have mostly overwritten the theme
-Changing global colors doesnt work
-changing background/foreground doesnt work
-changing opacity doesnt work...

I need to generate it from code behind because im changing it dynamically in one window
(or is it possible to define multiple AppBars in markup?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for effort, but changing opacity didnt to 0.999 didnt help either.

I found a solution!! And its quite simple :)

I Just take the old bar instead of creating a new one:

```
//Old Code
    ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

//New Code
    ApplicationBar.Buttons.Clear();
    ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Clear();
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
ApplicationBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(52,0,2,181);
ApplicationBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
```

You will get the same color in designer page by this way.

This (52,0,2,181) is the conversion value of #002B55

Comment: Thats what my HelperClass Actually did, sorry I forgot to change it for the post. I changed it now.
So problem still exists...

Answer (score 0):

On a fresh project, everything seems fine, here.

```
"- changing background/foreground doesnt work 
 - changing opacity doesnt work..."
```

Using the Application Bar sample, you provided in XAML, but with `Opacity=0.5`, I get this :

[image: your XAML AppBar but with Opac]

After I click the "Change Color" button, which does `ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1;`, I get this result :

[image]

(The background image is slightly moved up, because in first case we provided an opacity and in the second there was none explicitly specified and it seems the app bar didn't layered over the image, but to fix this you can set an `Opacity=0.999`, close to 1).

It must have something to do with all the theme overwriting you have done or some customization you attempted.

If this isn't quite helpful, provide me more details and I'll try to help as I can.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! This didnt help either but I found the solution now! I just dont create a new object of the applicationbar and take the current "this.Applicationbar" :)
Tommorow I Will post the solution as im locked currently